# Is it possible to use Subversion on low quality 3G network?

Tags: svn

If i checkout a big svn repository on low quality 3G/WiMAX network i often get an error "Could not read responce body: connection timed out". After that, my working copy is locked and "svn cleanup" is not working with error "Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in 'packages/univint/src'. 'packages/univint/src/Folders.pas' is not under version control'. Is it possible to somehow configure subversion not to corrupt all on network timeouts. Or maybe it's a way to somehow continue after working copy is corrupted after network timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html), you can resume an interrupted checkout:

> If you interrupt a checkout (or
>   something else interrupts your
>   checkout, such as loss of
>   connectivity, etc.), you can restart
>   it either by issuing the identical
>   checkout command again or by updating
>   the incomplete working copy:
>
> ```
> $ svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos/test mine
> A  mine/a
> A  mine/b
> ^C
> svn: The operation was interrupted
> svn: caught SIGINT
>
> $ svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos/test mine
> A  mine/c
> ^C
> svn: The operation was interrupted
> svn: caught SIGINT
>
> $ svn update mine
> A  mine/d
> Updated to revision 20.
> ```

If you are using the latest SVN release and this isn't working for you, then you might want to discuss this on users@subversion.apache.org and [file a bug report](http://subversion.apache.org/issue-tracker.html).

Answer (score 0):

i am doing exactly this using **tortiose-git** as svn client on a ms-windows laptop. **git** is a distributed sourcecode repository that can sync with svn.

distriuted means it has a local copy of the repository so once downloaded the repository many operations are local.

note: you have to learn how git differs from svn

Comment: As i mentioned, the problem is exactly with dunloading over unstable connection. By mentioning git, you mean that it will work fine over unstable network connection?

Comment: it works after download completed once. i did this first download when i had a better connection. after this there are only incremental down- and updloads that are more compact and work well when i am on travel in a train via gsm.